# convert integer to fixed point in division operation

Tags: vhdl, division

I have this code in my project.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library ieee_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;

entity sfixed_test is
 port(x1 : in integer :=20;
        x2 : in integer := 23;
        N : out sfixed( 8 downto -8));

end sfixed_test;

architecture Behavioral of sfixed_test is
    signal Ni,Nii,No,Noo,nb :integer;

signal Niii : sfixed(4 downto -20);
    signal Nn : sfixed(4 downto -20);
signal N1max : integer := 34;
    signal N1min : integer := 14;
    signal N2max : integer := 56;
    signal n2min : integer := 0;

begin


    Ni <= x1-N1min;
    Nii <= N1max-N1min;
    Niii <= to_sfixed(Ni/Nii,Niii);


    No <= x2-N2min;
    Noo <= N2max-N2min;
    Nn <= to_sfixed(No/Noo,Nn);

end Behavioral;
```

I want to convert result value from my division operation, but the value of **Niii** and **Nn** is zero went i try running my code in simulator. And te result of my project is not correct. 
Please to helping me.

Thank you

Comment: If you need floating point, don't declare all of your variables as integer.

Comment: Your code has semantic errors (e.g. Niii and Nn are declared twice both as integers and sfixed), it can't be simulated.  Remove the integer declarations. There's also no assignment to N. There may be more errors, ` sfixed(3 downto -40);` doesn't appear to have a large enough integer part for your default values of x1 and x2.

Comment: @user1155120 i have already change my code, but i'm still have zero value in niii and nn.

Comment: So, what values do you expect? As Ken White points out indirectly integer division gives integer results (Ni/Nii or 6/20 = 0; No/Noo or 23/56 = 0). You really want to do sfixed division not  conversion of the integer quotient. Convert the dividend and divisor to sfixed first noting arithmetic operations will effect the result length.

Comment: thank you for helping me everyone.